# oracle sqlloader column not allowed here ORA-00984

Tags: oracle, csv, sql-loader

I'm trying to use SQLLoader to load csv data into a table but i am receiving the following error - Record 1: Rejected - Error on table PMI_DATA_SPRINT_REPORTER.PERSON, column DATETIME_OF_BIRTH.
ORA-00984: column not allowed here

Tried to subvstr and to_date the data due to only needing YYYY-MM-DD -
 `DATETIME_OF_BIRTH "TO_DATE(substr(DATETIME_OF_BIRTH,1,10),'YYYY-MM-DD')",` but received the same error as above.

Any suggestions are appreciated, thanks.

**DDL of the table**

```
  CREATE TABLE "PERSON" 
   (    "PERSON_ID" NUMBER(19,0), 
    "GENDER_CONCEPT_ID" NUMBER(19,0), 
    "YEAR_OF_BIRTH" NUMBER(19,0), 
    "MONTH_OF_BIRTH" NUMBER(19,0), 
    "DAY_OF_BIRTH" NUMBER(19,0), 
    "DATETIME_OF_BIRTH" DATE, 
    "RACE_CONCEPT_ID" NUMBER(19,0), 
    "ETHNICITY_CONCEPT_ID" NUMBER(19,0), 
    "LOCATION_ID" NUMBER(19,0), 
    "PROVIDER_ID" NUMBER(19,0), 
    "CARE_SITE_ID" NUMBER(19,0), 
    "PERSON_SOURCE_VALUE" VARCHAR2(500 CHAR), 
    "GENDER_SOURCE_VALUE" VARCHAR2(500 CHAR), 
    "GENDER_SOURCE_CONCEPT_ID" NUMBER(19,0), 
    "RACE_SOURCE_VALUE" VARCHAR2(500 CHAR), 
    "RACE_SOURCE_CONCEPT_ID" NUMBER(19,0), 
    "ETHNICITY_SOURCE_VALUE" VARCHAR2(500 CHAR), 
    "ETHNICITY_SOURCE_CONCEPT_ID" NUMBER(19,0)
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 81920 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ;

  ALTER TABLE "PERSON" MODIFY ("ETHNICITY_CONCEPT_ID" NOT NULL ENABLE);
  ALTER TABLE "PERSON" MODIFY ("RACE_CONCEPT_ID" NOT NULL ENABLE);
  ALTER TABLE "PERSON" MODIFY ("YEAR_OF_BIRTH" NOT NULL ENABLE);
  ALTER TABLE "PERSON" MODIFY ("GENDER_CONCEPT_ID" NOT NULL ENABLE);
  ALTER TABLE "PERSON" MODIFY ("PERSON_ID" NOT NULL ENABLE);
```

**Control file**

```
load data 
infile 'filename.csv' "str '\r\n'"
append
into table PERSON
fields terminated by ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' AND '"'
trailing nullcols
           ( 
PERSON_ID integer,
GENDER_CONCEPT_ID integer,
YEAR_OF_BIRTH integer,
MONTH_OF_BIRTH integer,
DAY_OF_BIRTH integer,
DATETIME_OF_BIRTH DATE "YYYY-MM-DD",
RACE_CONCEPT_ID integer,
ETHNICITY_CONCEPT_ID integer,
LOCATION_ID integer,
PROVIDER_ID integer,
CARE_SITE_ID integer,
PERSON_SOURCE_VALUE CHAR(4000),
GENDER_SOURCE_VALUE CHAR(4000),
GENDER_SOURCE_CONCEPT_ID integer,
RACE_SOURCE_VALUE CHAR(4000),
RACE_SOURCE_CONCEPT_ID integer,
ETHNICITY_SOURCE_VALUE  CHAR(4000),
ETHNICITY_SOURCE_CONCEPT_ID integer)
```

CSV with an example record(unsure how to put an actual file here..)

```
PERSON_ID   GENDER_CONCEPT_ID   YEAR_OF_BIRTH   MONTH_OF_BIRTH  DAY_OF_BIRTH    DATETIME_OF_BIRTH   RACE_CONCEPT_ID ETHNICITY_CONCEPT_ID    LOCATION_ID PROVIDER_ID CARE_SITE_ID    PERSON_SOURCE_VALUE GENDER_SOURCE_VALUE GENDER_SOURCE_CONCEPT_ID    RACE_SOURCE_VALUE   RACE_SOURCE_CONCEPT_ID  ETHNICITY_SOURCE_VALUE  ETHNICITY_SOURCE_CONCEPT_ID
1000003049  8532    1934    6   30  1934-06-30T00:00:00-05:00   8527    38003564    0   180930  0       1:FEMALE    44394   26:WHITE    47289   10:NOT HISPANIC OR LATINO   44331
```

Comment: Tried the follow and it produces the same ' column not allowed here' aerror - DATETIME_OF_BIRTH "TO_DATE(substr(DATETIME_OF_BIRTH,1,10),'YYYY-MM-DD')",

Answer (score 2):

You need to use single quotes:

```
DATETIME_OF_BIRTH DATE 'YYYY-MM-DD',
```

Comment: Correction, that worked for 1 record but when including all of the records in the csv, i get this - ORA-01840: input value not long enough for date format. This is where i thought i needed to include a substr to pull only yyyy-mm-dd

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this do any good?

This is a line in the control file:

```
DATETIME_OF_BIRTH "to_date(substr(trim(:datetime_of_birth), 1, instr(:datetime_of_birth, 'T') - 1), 'yyyy-mm-dd')" ,
```